# Action bar disappeared on swipe tab view

Tags: android, android-tabs

I set swipe tab view on activity which is works fine but the problem is the Action bar of activity get disappeared while it was appeared before tab view. Please guide me how to again appear action bar at the top of tab view.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from activity_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

        // Locate the viewpager in activity_main.xml
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        ((ViewPager.LayoutParams) (findViewById(R.id.tab_strip)).getLayoutParams()).isDecor = true;

        // Set the ViewPagerAdapter into ViewPager
        viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    }

}
```

Tab1: simlar for tab2 and tab3
    public class FragmentTab1 extends Fragment {

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get the view from fragmenttab1.xml
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab1, container, false);
        return view;
    }

}
```

ViewPageAdapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
    // Tab Titles
    private String tabtitles[] = new String[] { "Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3" };
    Context context;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {

            // Open FragmentTab1.java
        case 0:
            FragmentTab1 fragmenttab1 = new FragmentTab1();
            return fragmenttab1;

            // Open FragmentTab2.java
        case 1:
            FragmentTab2 fragmenttab2 = new FragmentTab2();
            return fragmenttab2;

            // Open FragmentTab3.java
        case 2:
            FragmentTab3 fragmenttab3 = new FragmentTab3();
            return fragmenttab3;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabtitles[position];
    }
}
```

Styles.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
    </style>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.zohaibsiddique.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tab_strip"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you put your your manifest file here ?

Comment: i've put it. please see now

Comment: try to change `FragmentActivity` to `ActionBarActivity` or `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: thanks i also find this problem. I got answer

Comment: Kindly also tell me how to add Toolbar in main activity. I do it but when i setSupportActionbar(), the app get crashed. Please also see my edited code. @Lawrance

Comment: First thing is that you have to change your theme parent value to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`. Then remove both line `<item name="windowActionBar">true</item>` and `<item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the PagerTabStrip to display page title :

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
   android:id="@+id/vpPager"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

For more details, please see this link:

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter

Answer (score 0):

I resolves my problem by myself. I just extends MainActivity to AppCompatActivity and re-appear action bar.